# Android AppWidget - sometimes the onDataSetChanged() method doesn't get called

Tags: android, kotlin, android-widget

I noticed strange behavior of the widget in my app. Sometimes the `onDataSetChanged()` method from `RemoteViewsFactory` class is not called (of course when the app is in the background and widget is visible) even though the `notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged()` from `AppWidgetManager` class works correctly. I don't see any specific situation where this is happening - just sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. I spent a lot of time on debugging - everything looks like it's working fine.

```
            val ids: IntArray = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(ComponentName(context, MyWidgetProvider::class.java))
            appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(ids, R.id.appwidget_list_view)
```

I noticed that when I change it to:

```
            ids.forEach { id ->
            appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(id, R.id.appwidget_my_access_list_view)
            }
```

the problem occurs less frequently, but maybe it's coincidence.
Significant code snippets:

**MyWidgetProvider: AppWidgetProvider()**

```
    override fun onUpdate(
        context: Context,
        appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
        appWidgetIds: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds)

        appWidgetIds.forEach { id ->
            /* *** */
            val intent = Intent(context, MyWidgetRemoteViewsService::class.java).apply {
                putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, id)
                data = Uri.parse(toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME))
            }

            val remoteViews = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.my_widget).apply {
                setRemoteAdapter(R.id.my_widget_list_view, intent)
                /* *** */
            }
            
            appWidgetManager.apply {
                updateAppWidget(id, remoteViews)
            }
        }
    }
```

**MyWidgetRemoteViewsService: RemoteViewsService()**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MyWidgetRemoteViewsService : RemoteViewsService() {

    @Inject lateinit var itemStore: LockStore

    override fun onGetViewFactory(intent: Intent) = MyAccessRemoteViewsFactory(applicationContext, itemStore)
}
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
        <receiver
            android:name=".MyWidgetProvider"
            android:label="My app">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/appwidget_info"/>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".MyWidgetRemoteViewsService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS"/>
```